# tabularx \linewidth refitting not working

Tags: latex, tabular

I tell `tabularx` to refit my table to `\textwidth`, but it doesn't work (`\linewidth` doesn't work either). It would be ok if the font size gets reduced to achieve the desired result!

Interestingly, the first and last `\hline` are being resized to `\textwidth`, but the rest of the table is not (see picture).

Any help highly appreciated. Below find the code to my example:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{asdf}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccllllllll}
\hline
&  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{X = Gini} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{X = Selfishness} \\ \cline{3-10}
Treatment & Round & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WMW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Schlag} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WMW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Schlag} \\
&  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{reduced} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{full} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{reduced} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{full} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{reduced} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{full} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{reduced} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{full} \\ \cline{3-10}
\multirow{3}{*}{1} & 1 & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** \\
& 2 & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** \\
 & 3 & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* \\
\multirow{3}{*}{2} & 1 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 \\
 & 2 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 \\
 & 3 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: I have also tried adding \resizebox{\textwidth}{!} without success.

Comment: Never use resizebox for tables, that is about the worst you can do to your tex document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for further information.

Comment: Thank you. That helps, but now I get overlapping text. Is there an option for automatic font size adjustment?

Comment: Automatic font size adjustment is the worst idea ever for the same reason as to not use resizebox. Manually choose an appropriate font size, abrreviate the words, use another page geometry or restructure the table alltogether

Answer (score 1):

- Resizing of columns only works for type `X` columns, not for `l` or `c` columns
- `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` is useless
- even with resized columns, the table is too wide for a normal page. Either use a smaller font size, abbreviate some of the headers or make a landscape page

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\scriptsize
\caption{asdf}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXX}
\hline
&  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{X = Gini} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{X = Selfishness} \\ \cline{3-10}
Treat. & Round & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WMW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Schlag} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WMW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Schlag} \\
&  & reduced & full & reduced & full & reduced & full & reduced & full \\ \cline{3-10}
\multirow{3}{*}{1} & 1 & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** & .123*** \\
& 2 & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** & .123** \\
 & 3 & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* & .123* \\
\multirow{3}{*}{2} & 1 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 \\
 & 2 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 \\
 & 3 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 & .123 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```